# End of lines are grey with vim and zsh

Tags: bash, vim, zsh

I use vim and ZSH. When I open a document, the background seems to not be correct at the end of each lines as you can see here :

[image]

I tried with different colorscheme and it do the same thing. It works with bash.

What is the solution?

Comment: Check / compare the values for `$TERM` in bash and zsh; it's likely the latter one is wrong.

Comment: You are right. `$TERM` was `screen-256color` insteed of `xterm-256color`. Add an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These visual problems usually occur when Vim cannot fully control the terminal: Basic stuff like screen updates work, but things that are handled differently in different terminals (like setting the background color) do not.

Check and compare the values for `$TERM` in bash and zsh; it's likely the latter one is wrong. You shouldn't hard-code them in a startup file like `~/.bashrc`; instead, this variable should be set by your terminal emulator(s). This way, you can also work when you connect remotely via a different terminal emulator (e.g. PuTTY on Windows).